# Combinatorics-Summation doubt in the proof of the expectation of the Hypergeometric distribution.

Tags: combinatorics, probability-theory, probability-distributions, summation

The proof starts considering this equality:

$(d/dx (1+x)^A)(1+x)^B = A(1+x)^{A+B-1}$

Then it keep on changing every $(1+x)^{A or B}$ for its binomial coefficient. That 's what I don't understand. If I do it I get:

$\sum_{k=0}^{A}k\binom{A}{k}x^{k-1}   \sum_{l=0}^{B}\binom{B}{l}x^{l} =\sum_{n=0}^{A+B-1} \binom{A+B-1}{n} x^{n} $ ,where $k+l = n$

The proof gets a different result:
$\sum_{k+l=n}k\binom{A}{k}\binom{B}{l}= \binom{A+B-1}{n-1}$

I don't understand either what happened to the summation of the right side of the equation $ =A \binom{A+B-1}{n-1}$, as there is none.

The proof keeps on as follows:

Applying the former result $E[X]= \sum_{k}k \frac{\binom{b}{k}\binom{N-b}{n-k}}{\binom{N}{n}} = \frac{1}{\binom{N}{n}}b\binom{N-1}{n-1}= b \frac{n}{N}$

Answer (score 0):

The proof seems unnecessarily complicated.  You just need Vandermonde's identity
$$\textrm{(i)}\hspace{2em}\sum_{k+l=n}\binom ak\binom bl=\binom{a+b}n$$
together with the fact that
$$\textrm{(ii)}\hspace{2em}k\binom bk = b\binom{b-1}{k-1}.$$

Then the expected value of the hypergeometric distribution is $S/\binom Nn$, where
$$\begin{align}
 S&=\sum_k k\binom bk\binom{N-b}{n-k}\\
  &=b\sum_k\binom{b-1}{k-1}\binom{N-b}{n-k}\hspace{1em}&\textrm{by (ii)}\\
  &=b\binom{N-1}{n-1}\hspace{1em}&\textrm{by (i)}
\end{align}
$$

Your algebraic proof should follow this; note that Vandermonde is equivalent to
$$(1+x)^a (1+x)^b = (1+x)^{a+b}$$
and (ii) is equivalent to
$$\frac{d}{dx}(1+x)^b= b(1+x)^{b-1}.$$

Comment: I appreciate your help. I don't understand that (ii) is equivalent to $d/dx(1+x)^b = b(1+x)^{b-1}$.I tried to solve it using the binomial theorem. This is $k\sum_{k=0}^{b}\binom{b}{k}x^{k-1} = b \sum_{k=0}^{b-1}\binom{b-1}{k}x^k$. How can I from here get the result $k\binom{b}{k} = b \binom{b-1}{k-1}$?

Comment: Just compare coefficients of $x^{k-1}$ on both sides of the equation you wrote down.

Comment: I don't very well how to do this, as on the left side there is $x^{k-1}$ and on the right side $x^k$.What I did is to write everything in function of $x^{k-1}$.So I guess one need to have the same thing in each side of the equation to remove the summations. So after trying different changes in the right summation I found that the right side is equal to $b\sum_{k=1}^{b}\binom{b-1}{k-1}x^{k-1}$ and the left side is equal to $\sum_{k=1}^{b}k\binom{b}{k}x^{k-1}$ .Now I can remove the $\sum_{k=1}^{b}x^{k-1}$ in each side. Is this the way to do it?

Comment: Yes, that's an excellent way to think about it.  There are other ways as well, but they all amount to what you did.